# Draggable droppable - stay in position when dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

This is the code I have so far for my draggable-droppable-resizable functionality:

```
 var cont1 = $(this.el).find('.image');
    var cont2 = $(this.el).find('#container2');
    console.log(cont1);
    $(cont1).draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        revert: 'true'
    });

    $(cont2).droppable({
        accept: 'img',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $canvas = $(this);
            var $container = $('<div>');

            if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('canvas-element')) {
                var $canvasElement = ui.draggable.clone();
                $canvasElement.addClass('canvas-element');

                $container.draggable({
                    cursor: "move",
                    // delay: 1000,
                    scroll: false
                            // containment: "parent"
                }).resizable({
                    //containment: "parent",
                    handles: 'n, e, s, ne, nw, se, sw',
                    aspectRatio: true
                });

                $container.append($canvasElement).prependTo(cont2);

                $canvasElement.css({
                    left: $container.left,
                    top: $container.top,
                    position: 'relative',
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%'
                });
                //$canvasElement.css('left', ui.position.left-80+'px').css('top', ui.position.top-80+'px').appendTo(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

[Here's the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/E9y8Q/3/)

What I would like to achieve is for the dropped images to remain in the place where they were dropped.

There are also some other issues - the images that have already been dropped before change their positions after a new one gets dropped and I would like to get rid of this issue.

What can I change to implement that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `.image` elements to `position: absolute` when inside of the container.  You then need to calculate their `left` and `top` based on the position of the drop event and the offset of the container.

**CSS:**

```
#container2 .image{
    position: absolute;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var containerOffset = $container.offset();
$canvasElement.css({
    left: ui.position.left - containerOffset.left,
    top: ui.position.top - containerOffset.top
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9y8Q/7/